# Prove that the equation $x^4 = y^2 +z^2 +4$ has no integer solutions.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

> Prove that the equation $x^4 = y^2 +z^2 +4$ has no integer solutions.

I believe I have proved it for the case when both $y$ and $z$ are of the same parity.

**Case 1: When $y$ and $z$ are of the same parity.**
This proof is for the case when both are even. The other is similar.
$$x^4 = y^2 + z^2 + 4 \Longleftrightarrow 16x_1^4 = 4y_1^2 + 4z_1^2 + 4 = 4(y_1^2 + z_1^2 + 1) \Longleftrightarrow 4x_1^2 = y_1^2 + z_1^2 + 1$$

The LHS is $0 \pmod 4$ while the RHS is $1, 3 \pmod 4$. Contradiction.

I don't know how to proceed with Case 2 when $y$ and $z$ are of unlike parity. Could you give me some hints?

Is my proof for the first case correct?

Could you suggest some better proofs?

Thanks.

Comment: The last RHS can also be $2\pmod 4$, if for example $y_1$ is even and $z_1$ is odd. This is a detail though.

Comment: No, because if $y,z$ are both even, then $y_1,z_1$ (which I assume they are $y/2,z/2$; if that's wrong, you should specify what they are in the question body) can have either parity.

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: The case of odd $y,\,z$ is "similar" in that it has no solutions either; other than that, it's hardly similar and should not be waived away like that.

Comment: @IvanNeretin It leads to $16x_1^4 = 4(y_1^2 + y_1 + z_1^2 + z_1 +1) + 2$ which is clearly a contradiction. The RHS isn't divisible by 4 forget 16.

Comment: Yes, sure, but you have to say that explicitly.

Comment: hint: see $\mod 8$

Comment: It is in the form: $a^2 = b^2+c^2+d^2$

Comment: Factor $x^4-4$ and use what you know about sums of squares.

Comment: @MikeBennett $$(x^2-2)(x^2+2) = y^2 + z^2$$ So?

Comment: So if $p \equiv 3 \mod{4}$ is prime, how many times can $p$ divide the right hand side?

Comment: @MikeBennett Could you elaborate?

Comment: @MikeBennett Any even number of times?

Comment: The point is that, yes,  every prime $p \equiv 3 \mod{4}$ divides a sum of two squares an  even number of times.

Comment: @MikeBennett So? I still didn't get what you are trying to imply.

Comment: Now answer the same question about $x^2-2$.

Comment: @MikeBennett If $x$ is odd then an odd number of times. If $x$ is even then any number of times but we are arguing about the case when $x$ is odd so we need not look at this. And it will also divide a number like $x^2 + 2$ an odd number of times where $x$ is odd. So what's the use of it? Odd and odd add upto an even number. I do not seem to find a contradiction.

Comment: If $x$ is odd, what common factors can $x^2-2$ and $x^2+2$ have?

Comment: @MikeBennett None.

Comment: @MikeBennett They are relatively prime.

Comment: So, does there exist a prime $p \equiv 3 \mod{4}$ that divides $x^4-4$ an odd number of times?

Comment: @MikeBennett Yes. But there does not exist one which divides it an even number of times. I think you meant even?

Comment: @MikeBennett For such primes divide the RHS an even number of times.

Comment: No, I meant odd. There certainly can exist such primes dividing $x^4-4$ an even number of times (such as when $x=4$). That's not the point.

Comment: @MikeBennett But we're arguing for case 2 where $x$ is odd.

Comment: I give up. You appear to be reasonably determined not to understand.

Comment: @MikeBennett Sorry. Yes there exists such a prime.